# quiero poder llamar mis datos en una variable diferente

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
quiero poder sacar los datos de la variable data y agregarlos en un arreglo para luego poder llamar a cada uno

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Todo lo que sea código agrégalo directamente como texto, no le saques captura, es demasiado maluco ver un código como imagen, agregalo a la pregunta simplemente pegalo guíandote con las ayudas para hacer un bloque de código.

Comment: gracias bueno es la primera vez q pido ayuda xd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que se me ocurre para que puedas guardar los datos que guardas en la variable data es al principio de todo hacer una lista de Strings

`List< String > listaDatos = new ArrayList<>();`

cuando cojas el valor de la variable o cuando lo vayas a imprimir en pantalla data puedes hacer:

`listaDatos.add(data);`

Entonces luego tendrás la lista rellenada con los valores que te interesan y podrás tratarlo como quieras, usamos una lista porque en principio no se sabe todas las String que vas a guardar

En el caso de que necesariamente necesites un arreglo , la clase lista es fácilmente convertible a un arreglo de esta forma:

`String[] arregloDatos = listaDatos.toArray();`

Un saludo

Comment: gracias por tu recomendacion